# Demos not working on Windows 10

Tags: corda

I have been trying to run all the examples and demos provided by R3 Corda on my local machine which has windows 10 in it. 
https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V1.0/running-the-demos.html
While example 1 and 2 are working fine, but I am unable to run the demos. While the nodes are getting deployed, but once I run the nodes using runnodes command from command-line, they open in terminals and immediately close. Please can someone from #r3corda #corda team may help to sort this out.

Comment: After deploying the nodes, you should have a set of nodes in your build folder (e.g. `PartyA`, `PartyB`, etc.). Can you navigate to one of these node folders and run the node directly by running `java -jar corda.jar`? What does it output to the terminal window?

Comment: Hi Joel, yes if I run java -jar corda.jar against individual node folders then they run. However the next step is again a hassle. For example in notary-demo I ran all the 3 nodes manually with this command and finally when I run "gradlew samples:notary-demo:notarise", it gives below error 

....
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:790)
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler$sessionAndProducerPool$1.invok

Comment: Sounds like a bug in `runnodes.bat` :( - I'll investigate. Regarding the notary demo issue, you have to start the node webservers too. Normally `runnodes.bat` would do this, but you can also start them directly (`java -jar corda-webserver.jar`).

Comment: Can you update the question to say which Java version and which shell version you're using?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the similar issue on Win 10.
Running the following:

`>java -jar corda.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library. Reasons: [no jansi64-1.14 in java.library.path, no jansi-1.14 in java.library.path, no jansi in java.library.path,
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\jansi-64-1-6925657630491746639.14: Access is denied]`

Downloading the missing library to C:\windows reloved it.

Download Link:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjansi14jar.htm