# Can lauch corda nodes

Tags: corda

I’m trying to launch cordapp from tutorial https://docs.corda.net/hello-world-running.html on winodws 10 pro x64. But when I start runnodes.bat script, consoles are flashing and close after moment without starting nodes. What is possible problem? How i can fix it?

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728446/demos-not-working-on-windows-10 - if you could please provide the same output

Answer (score 0):

Some underlying issue is causing each node to fail to start. Unfortunately, because the nodes are starting in separate terminal windows that close automatically when the node process exits, you can't see the error messages.

You should run a single node by following the instructions here: https://docs.corda.net/running-a-node.html#starting-an-individual-corda-node. This will start the node in the same terminal window, allowing you to see the error message when the process exits. This error message should allow you to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already tried this way. I had output like this.
`$ java -Xmx2048m -jar corda.jar

` and  that's all

Comment: You type `java -Xmx2048m -jar corda.jar` and what happens? No output at all?

Comment: Yes, same result

Comment: Is java installed and functioning, with the correct version? What does `java -version` return? Corda requires a minimum of Java 8u171, and does not support Java 9 or higher.